# python copies variable by reference or by value

Tags: python, memory-management

We have variable in our script which has values like this:

```
result = {abc: [], xyz: []}
```

Now we create another variable like:

```
abc = result['abc']
```

So what will be the memory usage by this script. Will all the data from result will be copied in abc variable or just reference of that data? Will this increase my memory usage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you miss `''` around dictionary keys?

Comment: Any new variable will increase memory usage, even references. References need to store data about where they refer to.

Comment: Hey, sorry for that. I just added example here. The result object has some json from api.

Comment: Neither. There are no copies. `abc` refers to the *exact* same `list` object as `result['abc']`. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @chepner "`abc` refers to the exact same `list` object" - one could say that **is** copying the reference.

Comment: @MichaelM. Actually the issue is the data in result.abc is of size in gb and we are not using any other data from that object. So will creating new variable have impact on the memory used by script?

Comment: The 8 bytes needed for a second reference to the list is entirely negligible compared to the size of the list itself. (Or rather, the combined size of the elements referenced by the list.)

Comment: Ohh. so abc will consume memory in bytes r8?

Comment: @user11823877 Only on 64-bit machines. On a 32-bit machine, it will take 4 bytes.

Comment: @MichaelM. , the list in abc is a pandas dataframe. That wont matter while copying r8?

Comment: @chepner the list in abc is a pandas dataframe. That wont matter while copying r8?

Comment: No, because nothing is being copied (at least, not in any sense you should care about).

Comment: @chepner updating the abc wont create copy of that object? the values of result.abc will also get updated?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Yes, that's what it means for `result['abc']` and `abc` to be references to the same list. Variables are just *names* for references. Assigning to a name *never* makes a copy of the object being assigned to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all variables increase memory usage. This is because references need to store the memory address of what they refer to. However, references use a negligible about of memory (4 bytes on a 32-bit machine, 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine) compared to copying/creating a new list. Please see [Ned Batchelder
's article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) on how this all works.

To answer your question on whether or not a copy of the list will be made: no. Whenever you assign a variable to another variable of an object, the object is not copied. As chepner answered in a comment on your question, `abc` and `result['abc']` both point to the same list, so the list is not copied in memory.

(For future visitors: The original question has many comments that may be useful. If you can, I recommend you read through those too.)